# Did the US Floyd protests actually result in charges against the police officers involved

Tags: united-states, police, protests

As of late, I have seen many arguing that the protests and riots in the US about the killing of George Floyd have been directly responsible for the increased charges against Derek Chauvin, and the new charges against the other 3 officers involved.

Is there any direct evidence that the protests were responsible for the charges.? Or are the charges more likely directly linked to the ongoing investigations from various branches of government. If so, the original argument is a Post hoc logical fallacy.

Is there any evidence of the correlation between the protests and the new charges that I missed during my search?

Comment: I think this an interesting question but I don't think an answer that fits the format of this SE can be produced unless someone involved in charging decisions makes a public statement that the protests influenced their decision making. As far as I know, this has not yet happened.